# Creating a webpage to display the <init-param> of a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I was creating a webpage that will display the `<init-param>` values on the home page.

My `DD` looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CheckIt</servlet-name>
        </servlet-class>servlet.Test</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>param1</param-name>
            <param-value>LikeICare</param-value>

            <param-name>param2</param-name>
            <param-value>AgainLikeICare</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CheckIt</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My code for `servlet.Test` looks like this:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        String param1 = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("param1");
        String param2 = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("param2");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println(param1 + "<br>" + param2);

    }
}
```

and the home page is here:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Init Parameters  will be displayed here</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `deployment environment` looks like this:
[image]

**However I get a 404 error when I enter the URL in the browser** as : `http://localhost:8080/checkInit/home.html`

### Please tell me what went wrong

*the `classes` folder has proper structure as `servlet/Test.java`*

Comment: First, make sure your tomcat is running by accessing to `http://localhost:8080`. If that's ok, then try going to `http://localhost:8080/checkInit/home`, that should execute the `doGet` method of your servlet (after all, it's a get request).

Comment: Tomcat is running, no issues there but I still get a 404. Is my DD and the rest fine ?

Comment: Your code looks fine, maybe you have something else that you haven't shown us (but I doubt it). Maybe restart the tomcat in order to allow the changes. Also, since you're using Tomcat 7, you can use the benefits of servlets 3.0. Try the code sample on [the Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: There's a typo in your web.xml, did you copy-paste or type it out by hand into the question? Also, the URL you are calling does not match the one configured for the servlet.

Comment: copy-paste. What should be the URL pattern ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if tomcat was not running or port was wrong it will throw "connection refused" error on browser :). 404 is coming, means request is going to the webserver but, resource path is not getting resolved.

Comment: @BimaleshJha maybe, just maybe, Tomcat could not be running on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing like `http://localhost:8080/checkInit/home`
You are appending `.html` at the end in your URL:  `http://localhost:8080/checkInit/home.html`

In your DD you have configured the servlet to be invoked as `/home`

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CheckIt</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: OP has a *home.html* page in the root of the *checkInit* folder. Look at the image.

Comment: Check your context is loaded in tomcat and it is called **checkInit** case sensitive. usually the name of the war file would be your context name (I'm coming from Tomcat 6.x).